# Rails: render text gives missingtemplate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to do an AJAX call with Rails.  The call is to the change_profile action in my controller.  The contents of this action are as follows:

```
def change_profile
    @test = params[:test]
    puts "AAAAAAA #{@test}"
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
    end
    render(:text => "FINISHED THE AJAX REQUEST")
end
```

When I call this, however, the Rails console says:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template main/change_profile  ....
```

I don't understand why this is happening.  Since I'm rendering text, shouldn't it know not to try to find the template and just render the text?

Comment: That means you don't have a View called change_profile.

Comment: Right, why do I need one?  I'm just trying to send text back to the client in response to the AJAX request, a view would be totally superfluous. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Why do you have a `respond_to` block w/ HTML and JS formats if you want to render something else?

Comment: It's left over from something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When left without a `{}`, the `respond_to` block looks for a file called `change_profile.erb.js` or some other `change_profile.xxx.js`. Add your code within the `respond_to` block

```
def change_profile
    @test = params[:test]
    puts "AAAAAAA #{@test}"
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js {
         render :text => "FINISHED THE AJAX REQUEST"
       }
    end
end
```